# i want to navigate to dialog box that contains cancel and delete.I want to select delete option and come back to previous page

Tags: java, selenium

*********delete button from dropdown list

```
snW.SelectDropown_byXpath("STOCKTHRES_DEL_XPATH")
snW.getDriver().switchTo().activeelement();
clicking delete from populated dialog box
snW.clickById("STOCKTHRES_DELK")
```

---

Comment: i used to .activeelement() but its not working.pls help me

Comment: You want to press delete button in a pop up ??? Can you try switching to pop up and then clicking Delete button ??

Comment: yes.u r correct pankaj.i m trying to switch that is the problem

Comment: Can you share the screenshot or html source please !!

Comment: actually left navigation frame also active that y main frame is not finding the activeelements

Comment: If you don't share scrrenshot or html source, how can I help you... \

Comment: <iframe id="gsft_main" frameborder="0" title="Navigation Content" allowfullscreen="true" name="gsft_main" webkitallowfullscreen="true" src="home_splash.do?sysparm_direct=true" mozallowfullscreen="true" class="ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-center ui-layout-pane-hover ui-layout-pane-center-hover ui-layout-pane-open-hover ui-layout-pane-center-open-hover" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: 7px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 265px; width: 1038px; z-index: 0; display: block; visibility: visible;"></iframe>                                                 above are main iframe

Comment: Below are the populating cancel or delete html source

Comment: this is populated delete buttn html                                                             <div id="delete_confirm_list" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" class="modal in" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delete_confirm_list_title" data-readonly="false" data-has-help="false" style="display: block; z-index: 1060;"> <div class="modal-dialog modal-alert">  <div class="modal-content">   <header class="modal-header">    <button data-dismiss="GlideModal" class="btn btn-icon close icon-cross">